# VSCode - Select word or function which will find the usages like intelliJ ide

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, intellij-14

In IntelliJ if you highlight the word for function by holding ctrl + click > it will highglight all the usages found in the entire project. See screen shot below

[image]

Similary I am looking for some VSCODE extensions to achieve the same functionality. It is really helpful in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [find all references](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek) is what you are after.

[image]

This is [bound](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) to <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f12</kbd> by default

Comment: I was looking for this extension but can we bind it ctrl + click?

Comment: No. Customizable mouse shortcuts are not supported as of VS Code 1.19. Tracked here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3130

Comment: BUT this can not show the usage type like Value write, Value read, import, comment.